# use dll of winform in a website

Tags: c#, winforms, dll

I have a winform application and I'm using an extra dll that I've created. I know that when I open the application and the .dll are not in the same folder, the application won't work.
Now, I want to upload the application to my website so the client will open it without saving, so how can I use the dll and the application on the client computer without any installation?

Comment: You could embed the dll into your application (using ILMerge, for example), but I'm curious as to why you don't want to perform installation?

Comment: The application is meant to be use by the clients just once, that's why I don't want them to install it.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Click-once-deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28v=vs.120%29.ASPX). It's a technique to deploy your content to a computer where the user has no administrative privileges, by supplying a downloadable package with all components that is easily updatable.